# ArcMap function in field calculator not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

Trying to return everything except the last element in a field after splitting it. Using ArcMap 10.2.2 in the field calculator.

```
!ST_NAME!.split(" ")[:-1]
```

This returns a null value in attribute table. If a I use the same approach in python interactive window it seems to work:

```
a = "Johnny be good"

>>> b = a.split(" ")[0:-1]
>>> b
['Johnny', 'be']
```

Comment: The return value is a list, which is not compatible to the field, which is rejected by the parser hence the null value. To use this in a field calculation for a string field you need to 'join' it " ".join(!ST_NAME!.split(" ")[:-1]) to make it into a string.

Comment: Another approach you can use would be to find the rightmost space and then slice into the string with that index. `f = "101 first street"; f[:f.rfind(" ")]`

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my previous comment...

The problem with your statement is that the returned value from [string.split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) is a list and the field you're trying to calculate into is a string, these types are incompatible so the parser ignores the value and sets the string to null.

To turn a list into a string you need to use [join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm):

```
>>> a = "Johnny be good"
>>> b = a.split(" ")[0:-1]
>>> print b
['Johnny', 'be']
>>> c = " ".join(b)
>>> print c
Johnny be
>>>
```

`b` is a list object, `c` is a string... So to field calculate *everything but the last word in a string* into a string field use:

```
" ".join(!ST_NAME!.split(" ")[:-1])
```